# Changing google maps marker property after clicking button inside info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, infowindow

I have markers on a map. I set the opacity of the marker dependent on the date in JSON.

Because of this when the map loads, some of the markers are 0.5 opacity, some are 1 opacity.

Inside the marker's info window there is a button. When I click this button I want to change the opacity to 1.

Below is some snippets of my code to show you how I have it setup at the moment.

Any help would be much appreciated

---

```
//For every item in JSON
$.each(dbJSON, function(key, data) {

    var opacity = 1;
    var today = new Date();
    var fadeDate = new Date(data.last_rated); //get the date last rated                 
    fadeDate.setDate(fadeDate.getDate() + 1); //and add 1 date to it to specify the day when the icon should fade

    if(Date.parse(today) > Date.parse(fadeDate)) {
        console.log('fade');
        opacity = 0.5;
    } else {
        console.log('show');
        opacity = 1;
    }

    var postal_town = data.location;
    geocoder.geocode( { 'address': postal_town}, function(results, status) {
        //...
        console.log(opacity);

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: results[0].geometry.location,
            title: data.manufacturer_name,
            icon: image,
            rating: data.rating,
            opacity: opacity
        });

        markers[data.id] = marker;

        marker.addListener('click', function() {

            var contentString = '<div id="content">'+
                '<h1>' + data.manufacturer_name + '</h1>' +
                '<button id="seen-it" data-rating="' + data.rating + '" data-entry-id="' + data.id + '">Seen it</button>' +
                '<p><strong>Rating: </strong><span id="rating">' + markers[data.id].rating + '</span></p>' +
                '</div>';

            infowindow.setContent(contentString);
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });
    });
});
```

---

```
//Do something when the #seen-it button is clicked
$(document).on('click', '#seen-it', function(event){
    //...
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you have the id of the marker stored in the `data-entry-id` you could use (*assuming the `markers` variable is accessible from your handler*)

```
$(document).on('click', '#seen-it', function(event){
    var markerId = $(this).data('entry-id');
    markers[markerId].setOpacity(1);
});
```

Comment: That works and i'm not entirely sure why! :) Thank you

Comment: @OliverEvans let me know which part confuses you and I will try to explain.

Comment: Nevermind I get it. I thought you were changing the opacity value on the object, and missed that you're using the setOpacity method. Thank you

Comment: @OliverEvans exactly. Glad to help.